# Target immediate parent with ampersand (SCSS)

Tags: sass

I'm experiencing what I think is odd behavior in scss.

I have a class nested 2 levels deep and I'm trying to target the immediate parent with an ampersand but it's, instead, targeting the parent's parent.

```
.one {
      .two{
        .three & {
          background:red;
          //should be .one .three .two right?
          //instead targets .three .one .two
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's an example of this behavior on codepen http://codepen.io/gpspake/pen/KpeEXp

Comment: thats just confusing to have it at the end.

Comment: Is this a bug report (hint: SO isn't for bug reports) or do you have a technical problem here?  The expected result is `.three .one .two` because the `&` represents the entire resolved selector preceding the current level of nesting.

Comment: @DanielA.White This seems to be a common use for the ampersand you'll find in a lot of [examples](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand). I use it often, actually. What's odd is that it targets the root parent in this case and not the immediate parent.

Comment: @cimmanonNot Thanks. That clears things a little. So how might one target the immediate parent from within a nested class or is that not possible?

Comment: Targeting it to do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior, according to [Referencing Parent Selectors: &](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

I would not recommend using this technique, because it's counter intuitive.

Comment: Thanks @halfzebra, guess you're right. "& will be replaced with the parent selector as it appears in the CSS. This means that if you have a deeply nested rule, the parent selector will be fully resolved before the & is replaced." Using & in this way can still be pretty powerful so I wouldn't discount it entirely but that answers the question :)

Comment: That's not really an answer.  It *is* possible to make modifications to any part of the selector you want, but the OP never specified *what* they wanted to do with it.